# SQL Server - windows auth

Tags: php, sql-server, iis

I have 2 servers:

Windows Server 2008 with SQL SERVER 2012

Windows Server 2008 with IIS 8

I need login from client machine to SQL server through IIS server use php application.

I read many articles and configure all and it works, but i have a problem - it work correctly only in IE browser (or EDGE), but not in Chromium-based or Firefox browsers.

If I launch once IE, php app succefull connect to SQL server, else in not IE browsers i got error NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON.

I always succefull logon on IIS (check `$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'];`)

Need help

Comment: How do you connect to SQL Server (which PHP extension do you use)? And, if possible, sample code will help here.

Comment: PHP 7.3.7 and sqlsrv 5.6.1

It is simple code to check connection
print $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'];
$serverName = "serverName\instanceName";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"Archive");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);


if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

Comment: How do you pass user credentials from client to server? You write only, that it works for IE and Edge.

Answer (score 0):

IIS needs to pass a Kerberos ticket to SQL Server for this scenario to work. IE is picking up the workstation session ticket, whereas Firefox is negotiating its own authentication (and not Kerberos).

To Enable Integrated Windows Authentication (IWA) in Mozilla Firefox you could follow the below steps:

1. Open Firefox
2. In the address bar, type about:config. At the prompt that warns to proceed with caution, agree to continue.
3. After the config page loads, in the filter box type: network.automatic. You should see a search result of network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris

   - Modify network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris by double-clicking the row, and then enter https://your_SecureAuth_FQDN.com
   - Multiple sites can be added by comma delimiting them, as in this example: https://your_SecureAuth_FQDN.com, https://www.replacewithyourintranetsite.com
4. Click "OK" and Restart Firefox